# Append Json object from database to HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, json

I am trying to create a one page app that searches weather by a zip code and displays the results. I am accessing a weather database, but I am stuck on how to append a specific json object to my dom

Incomplete javascript

```
 $(function() {
$("#getzip").submit(function() {
var zip_data = $(this).serialize();
    $.getJSON("get_weather.php",zip_data, function(data); {
    ("#output").append(current_obervation.temperature_string); // this is what I want it to do tho obviously incorrect


  });
 });
})
```

HTML

```
<h1>Weather</h1>
<hr />
<form method="get" action="get_weather.php" id="getzip">
<p>
  <label for="zip">ZIP:</label>
  <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip">
  <input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit" >
</p>
```

```
<pre id="output">
</pre>
```

PHP

```
<?php
 $zip = isset($_GET['zip']) ? $_GET['zip'] : $_POST['zip'];
 $weather_data = file_get_contents("http://api.wunderground.com/api/6d125bc5977276ee/conditions/q/{$zip}.json");
echo $weather_data 
?>
```

And a small sample of what the database returns. How would I pinpoint temperature and append it to the dom?

```
current_observation": {
"image": {
  "url": "http://icons-ak.wxug.com/graphics/wu2/logo_130x80.png",
  "title": "Weather Underground",
  "link": "http://www.wunderground.com"
   "temperature_string": "53.5 F (11.9 C)",
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help but I discovered this way works best

```
$(function() {
$("#getzip").submit(function() {
  var zip_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.getJSON("get_weather.php", zip_data, function(data) {
    $("#output").empty();
    $('#output').append(JSON.stringify( data.current_observation.temperature_string, " "));                   
  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "output" to your html.

```
<div id="output"></div>

$(function() {
    $("#getzip").submit(function() {
        var zip_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.getJSON("get_weather.php",zip_data, function(data); {
             $('#output').html(data.current_observation.temperature_string);
        });
    });  
})
```

Comment: it was there, it just was not formatted to correctly in my post

Comment: Change from 'pre' to 'div'.

Comment: Also, use console.log (data) and see in the console what does your get_weather.php returns to your script.

Comment: And, finally, you have ';' after 'function (data)'. Since I copied it from your script - I also have it in my answer. Remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$('#output').append(data.current_observation.temperature_string)
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NZf6r/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you actually need.[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/symonsarwar/NZf6r/10/)

```
$('#output').append(data.current_observation.image.temperature_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.get( "get_weather.php", function( data ) {       
 $( "#output" ).append( "Temperature: " + data.current_observation.temperature_string    )},"json" );

// mentioned "json" as 3rd parameter as it emits json response
```

Reference from last example [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) .